# Eclipse (java) Run multi client and one server same time

Tags: eclipse, server, client, multi-project

Can I use Eclipse to run multiple java application ( one Server class and two client classes) which mean I may need three Console View.  
  
I know I can "copy and paste" the Eclipse folder three times to solve this problem but it will SO un-convenient to simulate 10 clients same time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Eclipse CDT's Launch Group.

First, create the Debug Configuration for the server and two clients, in this case.

Second, create a new "Launch Group" Debug Configuration, adding the server and two clients to it.

Third, run the new Launch Group, which should run the server and two clients.

[Creating a Launch Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrFD5.png)